# Selecting a Subset of Columns for BigQuery Table Load

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I am working with 3rd-party dataset that is loaded into a Google Bucket, and I am attempting to load it into BigQuery to run some pruning steps. The dataset has a set of columns that don't follow BQ column naming convention, and thus the load fails when considering the full file (Which is approximately 4,000 partitions and a little more than a TB)

I can build out a distributed Python process to drop/rename the offending columns, but this seems like an ineffective use of computational resources. Does BigQuery offer some direct method of loading a subset of columns from a parquet file?

Comment: I believe there is no built in function in BQ for this. I would suggest filing a feature request for this function here: https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers Please see details in the documentation on how to gain traction.

Comment: Are some of your column names breaking the rules described here:

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-parquet#column_name_conversions

Comment: Correct. Some of the columns start with an integer value, such as `30_day_counter`. I don't need to load this column into BQ, but it effectively stops me from loading the table.